# Cannot get url using urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm learning Python, and the case for today is download text from a webpage.
This code works fine:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = "http://www.pracuj.pl"
url = urllib2.urlopen(base_url+"/praca/big%20data;kw").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,"html.parser")

for k in soup.find_all('a'):
    if "offer__list_item_link_name" in k['class']: 
        link = base_url+k['href']
        print link
```

So it prints all links like this:

```
http://www.pracuj.pl/praca/inzynier-big-data-cloud-computing-knowledge-discovery-warszawa,oferta,4212875
http://www.pracuj.pl/praca/data-systems-administrator-krakow,oferta,4204109
http://www.pracuj.pl/praca/programista-java-sql-python-w-zespole-bigdata-krakow,oferta,4204341
http://www.pracuj.pl/praca/program-challenging-projektowanie-i-tworzenie-oprogramowania-katowice,oferta,4186995
http://www.pracuj.pl/praca/program-challenging-analizy-predyktywne-warszawa,oferta,4187512
http://www.pracuj.pl/praca/software-engineer-r-language-krakow,oferta,4239818
```

When add one line to assign new address, to fetch each lines content :

```
url2 = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_page.py", line 10, in <module>
    url2 = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
NameError: name 'link' is not defined
```

What is wondering, it doesn't work only when in `for` loop. When I add the same line outside the loop it works.

Can you point what I'm doing wrong?

Pawel

Answer (score 1):

I assume your line `url2 = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()` is not in the same scope as your `link` variable. The `link` variable is local to the scope of the `for` loop, so it will work if you move your call inside of the for loop.

```
for k in soup.find_all('a'):
    if "offer__list_item_link_name" in k['class']: 
        link = base_url+k['href']
        url2 = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
```

If you want to process the url outside of the for loop, save your links in a list:

```
links = []
for k in soup.find_all('a'):
    if "offer__list_item_link_name" in k['class']: 
        link = base_url+k['href']
        links.append(link)

for link in links:
    #do stuff with link
```

Answer (score 0):

That actually does work for me. How were you formatting your code?

Mine looks vaguely like this:

```
for k in soup.find_all('a'):
if "offer__list_item_link_name" in k['class']: 
    link = base_url+k['href']
    #print link
    url2 = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
    print url2
```

and works just fine.